# how to select data depending status in out return

Tags: sql, sql-server

how to select data based on `lot_product` that has a certain status?
such as
lot product has

in -> display data IN

In, OUT -> not showing

In, out, return -> display data return

In, out, return, out -> not showing

In, out, return, out, return -> display data return (last)

In, out, return, out, return, out -> not showing

I have sample data like this

```
lot_product kode_rak    item_type   item_size   operator    qty_mtr qty_mtr_sisa    status  tanggal

A   B.1.1   SC003       0.30        AHMAD ANDREANSYAH   95000   0   IN  08/10/2021 19:14:09,000
A   B.1.1   SC003       0.30        AHMAD ANDREANSYAH   95000   0   OUT 08/10/2021 19:48:45,000
A   C.1.2   SC003       0.30        AHMAD ANDREANSYAH   0   25000   RETURN  08/10/2021 19:50:35,000
B   F.1.1   VS012       1.25        AHMAD ANDREANSYAH   35000   0   IN  08/10/2021 19:54:04,000
C   D.1.1   SS005       0.50        AHMAD ANDREANSYAH   78500   0   IN  08/10/2021 20:04:11,000
C   D.1.1   SS005       0.50        AHMAD ANDREANSYAH   78500   0   OUT 08/10/2021 20:06:24,000
D   H.1.1   SS003       0.30        AHMAD ANDREANSYAH   102700  0   IN  08/10/2021 20:08:24,000
D   H.1.1   SS003       0.30        AHMAD ANDREANSYAH   102700  0   OUT 08/10/2021 20:09:25,000
D   M.1.1   SS003       0.30        AHMAD ANDREANSYAH   0   50000   RETURN  08/10/2021 20:11:15,000
D   M.1.1   SS003       0.30        AHMAD ANDREANSYAH   50000   0   OUT 08/10/2021 20:12:44,000
D   H.2.3   SS003       0.30        AHMAD ANDREANSYAH   0   20000   RETURN  08/10/2021 20:14:12,000
D   H.2.3   SS003       0.30        AHMAD ANDREANSYAH   20000   0   OUT 08/10/2021 20:16:15,000
```

my query

```
select
dt_prod,
    (
    SELECT TOP
        1 rel2.lot_product 
    FROM
        prod_scan_item_fg AS rel2 
    WHERE
        rel2.lot_product = prod_scan_item_fg.lot_product 
        AND rel2.dt_prod = prod_scan_item_fg.dt_prod 
        AND rel2.tanggal >= prod_scan_item_fg.tanggal 
        
    ORDER BY
        rel2.tanggal DESC 
    ) AS lot_product,
    kode_rak,
    item_type,
    item_size,
    operator,
    qty_mtr,
    qty_mtr_sisa,
    status,
    tanggal 
FROM
    prod_scan_item_fg 
WHERE
    status IN ( 'IN', 'RETURN' )
GROUP BY
dt_prod,
    lot_product,
kode_rak,
    item_type,
    item_size,
    operator,
    qty_mtr,
    qty_mtr_sisa,
    status,
    tanggal
```

expected data

```
lot_product kode_rak    item_type   item_size   operator    qty_mtr qty_mtr_sisa    status  tanggal
A   C.1.2   SC003       0.30        AHMAD ANDREANSYAH   0   25000   RETURN  08/10/2021 19:50:35,000
B   F.1.1   VS012       1.25        AHMAD ANDREANSYAH   35000   0   IN  08/10/2021 19:54:04,000
```

Comment: Make it easy to assist you - simplify! E.g. sample data like `x`, `y` and `z` are much easier to get than `YVS012BE621092791`, `YVS012E3621092791` and `YVS012B3621029791`. [mcve]

Comment: Much better now!